# Removing the square-brackets and their contexts from an expression

Tags: syntax

Suppose I start with an expression like `y[t] + x[t]`: is there a function that lets me remove the `[t]` elements, so I obtain the expression `y + x`?

Comment: What you asking is rather strange. What a you trying to accomplish? Also, are you aware that the Mathematica evaluator sees your expression as `Plus[x[t], y[t]]`; that there is another level of square brackets that the notebook editor doesn't normally show?

Comment: Imagine this: I have an expression where `x[t]` and `y[t]` are functions that I evaluate for different values of `t`.  I want to perform other manipulations of the expression, such as taking derivatives with respect to `x` or `y`, that no longer require keeping the argument `[t]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
exp= y[t] + x[t] ;
exp /.Level[#->Head@#&/@Level[exp,1],1]
```

> x+y

Comment: Can you tell me more about the syntax you're using here?

Comment: this replaces `x[t]` with `Head[x[t]]` etc...

Answer (score 5):

For your example at least, the following works.

```
Replace[y[t] + x[t], u_[_] -> u, 2]
```

> `x + y`

#### Update

As I suspected, for the real problem underlying the question, the above method is not going to work. I would recommend using `ReplaceAll` and give a separate rule for each specific head involved. Like so.

```
Sin[y[t] + x[t]]/(1 + x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^(1/2) /. {x[t] -> x, y[t] -> y}
```

> ```
> Sin[x + y]/Sqrt[1 + x^2 + y^2]
> ```

As you see from the above example, this approach will handle quite complex expression involving `x[t]` and `y[t]` quite robustly.

Comment: +1. I like `Head /@ (y[t] + x[t])` for weird usage points...

Comment: This worked nicely - can you explain more the syntax with `u_[_]` here?

Comment: @dtcitron. `u_[_]` is a pattern that matches any expression with a single argument. When a match is made, Mathematica will bind `u` (temporarily) to the expression's head. The rule in which `u_[_]` appears tells `Replace` that, when a match occurs, to replace the matched expression with what `u` is bound to, namely the head.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
f = (ToString /* StringDelete[Shortest["["~~___~~"]"]]);
f[y[t] + x[t] - z[u]]
(* x + y - z *)
```